# Type inference from switch case return with Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

type of the functions

```
type fn01 = (name: string) => void
type fn02 = (age: string) => void
type fn03 = (description: number) => void
```

I have this case:

```
type Options = 'op1' | 'op2' | 'op3'

const test = (options) => {
    switch(options) {
          case 'op1':
            return fn01
          case 'op2':
            return fn02
          case 'op3':
            return fn03
          default
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Function Usage:

```
const chosenFN = test('op1');

choseFN()
```

When using the chosenFN it should show the type from the function that would be fall into the switch case, but instead shows a Intersection of all of them.

What am I missing? 
I thought that since the function that's used is inside of a switch case, it would infer the correct type based on the argument passed.

Thanks, 
Renan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to achieve that, you need to use function overloads - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads:

```
type Options = 'op1' | 'op2' | 'op3'
type fn01 = (name: string) => void
type fn02 = (age: string) => void
type fn03 = (description: number) => void

// here overloads - define output for every input
function test(a: 'op1'): fn01;
function test(a: 'op2'): fn02;
function test(a: 'op3'): fn03;

function test(options: Options) {
    switch(options) {
      case 'op1':
        return (name: string) => {}
      case 'op2':
        return (age: string) => {}
      case 'op3':
        return (description: number) => {}
      default:
        throw new Error('no such value')  
      }
}

const f = test('op1') // it is fn01
```

Comment: I like your solution but it will not protect when returning wrong type, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995#issuecomment-588375563

Answer (score 9):

The compiler does not generally infer function return types that depend on which specific value was input into it.  [Control flow type analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) acts to narrow the types of concrete-typed variables inside the function implementation, and so the `switch` statement serves to know that `options` is exactly `op2` (for example) inside the relevant `case` block, but control flow analysis doesn't do much to the return type of the function.

Generally the inferred return type of a function will be the union of all the types that are `return`ed from the function, irrespective of control flow analysis.  That means the signature of `test()` is inferred as something like `function test(options: Options): fn01 | fn02 | fn03 | null`.

When you go to actually call a function of type `fn01 | fn02 | fn03 | null`, you will run into trouble.  With [the `--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) on, you can't call it at all (and you probably *should* use the `--strict` compiler options, since they catch bugs).

Assuming you have a function of type `fn01 | fn02 | fn03` (and you've verified that it's not `null`), you still can't really call it.  Support for calling unions of functions was [improved](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) in TypeScript 3.5, but still, the only safe thing you can pass to a union of functions is the *intersection* of its parameters.  And the intersection `string & string & number` has no members (there are no values that are both `string` and `number` in JavaScript), meaning it is `never`, and thus it's completely uncallable.

---

So, that's why it doesn't work.  To fix it, you'll either have to use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), or annotate the function to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), where `options` is of generic type `O extends Options`.

Overloads are easy but they are not really type safe.

The generic type has the potential to be more type safe, but not when you use `switch`, which exposes a [current limitation of TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) whereby control flow analysis is unable to narrow the types of generic-typed variables.

The safest way to do it would be to use a mapping object instead of a `switch` statement:

```
const test = <O extends Options>(options: O) => ({
    op1: fn01,
    op2: fn02,
    op3: fn03
}[options]);
```

This is properly inferred to be a generic function where each input type maps to a particular function output type:

```
const chosenFN = test('op1'); // (name: string) => void
chosenFN("okay") // okay
test('op2')("age is a string I guess"); // okay
test('op3')(8675309); // okay
```

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMxQBgEYAueAChSgFsQTMYBLFAcwEp4BeAPngDcl7gAWABQoSLATJ0WXHgBMJUlCY14dRqw7c+AkWOhxEqTDnwBmRaDRgGABwz1UJFAFdKAIxAw2XXvyHCIhgAnrYIAPL2jugc8ADkSLYEcfAAPvGJcinpCbZmcSKFwlImGCAm7PAAPOHwIAAeZSjAaPCRDsacpIkd6CThPtykAN4i8OPwicSmhAA0YxOZJLJy88ITk3nL5iIAvgDaPdFoALosANxFJVhgABZIaCAoAGIAcrFlmKS5yRfwAPT-MgUai0DAMZiDPy6Yr3R4vV6kABESAA1lBgki2IDJujgkFyhhvpk4ixkcoEPRWlA1OCNPAAJLwJgucpoLHnAFAtEYglfXL5MkADgAbAB2ACsZjwAE4-jiecEgA)

Comment: Thank you very much. Very well explained. You got it very well to the point. +1