# is there any way to let Typescript infer the return type from the function argument value?

Tags: typescript

is there any way to let Typescript infer the return type from the valueType argument instead of overloads?

```
 type ValueType = 'integer' | 'string' | 'number' | 'date' | 'dateTime' | 'boolean' | '';

   function toValueType<S>(v: S, valueType: 'integer'): number;
   function toValueType<S>(v: S, valueType: 'number'): number;
   function toValueType<S>(v: S, valueType: 'date'): Date | undefined;
   function toValueType<S>(v: S, valueType: 'dateTime'): Date | undefined;
   function toValueType<S>(v: S, valueType: 'string'): string;
   function toValueType<S>(v: S, valueType: ''): S;
   function toValueType<S>(v: S, valueType: ValueType): any {
        switch (valueType) {
            case 'integer':
                return To.int(v); // return number
            case 'number':
                return To.number(v); // return number
            case 'date':
                return To.date(v); // return Date|undefined
            case 'dateTime':
                return To.dateTime(v); // return Date|undefined
            case 'string':
                return To.string(v); // return string
            case 'boolean':
                return To.boolean(v); // return boolean
            default:
                return v; // return source
        }
    }
```

Comment: For the first one you can make a generic based on the keys of `To` and what it returns. See https://tsplay.dev/Nl8KXN. Does that solve your problem? If so I can write up that answer for you.

Comment: As for your second function, it's best to ask one question at a time. So I recommend you [edit] your question and remove and ask another question relating to that function.

Comment: You can use a mapping of `ValueType` string literal to expected result type like this: https://tsplay.dev/wR7b1N If that answers your question, I can write it up as one. If not, what did I miss?

Comment: @AlexWayne Thank you for your help, I came up with a solution close to this one but we still have to use one overload function for default.

Comment: @jsejcksn Thank you, it solves my problem. I write something related to that but did not work with the default value, and it works when I Created ValueMap as a generic interface. but it was dirty code I did not like it. your code is way better I liked it.

Comment: I removed the second question and create a new one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76329404/how-can-we-infer-the-return-type-from-the-function-argument-if-it-is-a-string-ar

Comment: @jsejcksn When I implemented the function, it did not work unless I cast every case to any, you can see here: https://shorturl.at/fkuY9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) which represents a mapping of each string literal in your `ValueType` union to its corresponding expected return type, and create another [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter to use for selecting the appropriate type in a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) return type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QLJzFAvFA3gKCigCMB7UhCOAOwC4TzKaBuQqAEzmAnoBEvoAHyhJq7CADMAltQjtWRTtwAqUgLY8o-blGGjx02fLYzuAcwgAnetSRriVhVFv2rNuw8tOAzsEsyzel9-ajNWAF9WfFBIWEQUZXBoHABrCBBSCTjkNAxdKAAiAqjxAGMEOEtoCVFS4ClSaihgUngcxMgAHmUAGigAaSgIAA9uMW9shKSAPgAKNgA3el7F+IgOzX6e-ABKekGRsfYJtIystpR0TAB+SdywAG1+gF0oZZKIcsroUsbfKCWeCgAH0YpoCiM4GowJQClBIvh8L9qP9LAAGbDNVprDazBZ9ApkChUagFHZOIgAekpAD1rojkaiAIyYloXdZJPEEpQQMkUqDUukMv7AKCWABMrOx7U5+MKPNUGj5bCptPpSJFYoAzFL2bi5QVTBALJZlURVUKNSjRZYACy6nGygkuTxm82C9WMm0AVgdMsgXMKwQCbotns1lgAbH6pgGDaGBWrEWzHXGCd5SBpgAALAJDBDeXnkgUAKigAFFLJZSJYVeb6w2AH7NluttuN-AAQUsZjsEGoosyzSSUAA5AUM1nc6F84WCqOoFIJtRSKK4N5vFIzNQ4MRKFioGBKlCINxLFAh2Cx3qkqOAHSzcVa23enZQEuU-BAA)

```ts
type ValueMap = {
  boolean: boolean;
  date: Date | undefined;
  dateTime: Date | undefined;
  integer: number;
  number: number;
  string: string;
};

type ValueType = keyof ValueMap | "";

declare function toValueType<T, K extends ValueType>(
  v: T,
  valueType: K,
): K extends keyof ValueMap ? ValueMap[K] : T;

declare const v: { _type: "example" };

const r0 = toValueType(v, "boolean");
    //^? const r0: boolean

const r1 = toValueType(v, "date");
    //^? const r1: Date | undefined

const r2 = toValueType(v, "dateTime");
    //^? const r2: Date | undefined

const r3 = toValueType(v, "integer");
    //^? const r3: number

const r4 = toValueType(v, "number");
    //^? const r4: number

const r5 = toValueType(v, "string");
    //^? const r5: string

const r6 = toValueType(v, "");
    //^? const r6: { _type: "example"; }

toValueType(v, "something else"); /* Error
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Argument of type '"something else"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueType'.(2345) */
```

Comment: I got the idea and I love it but when I implement it it did not work without casting to any. can you give a look at the link please: https://shorturl.at/fkuY9

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76328916/is-there-any-way-to-let-typescript-infer-the-return-type-from-the-function-argum?noredirect=1#comment134599888_76329460) @AhmedAlbahrawy (1) Type inference in the function body is not strictly related to the details of your question. (2) This is a known bug/limitation in TS; the inference failure is detailed in these GitHub issues ([ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998), [ms/TS#13995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995)) and [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58673995/438273).

Comment: No conditional type needed: https://tsplay.dev/we8AEW