# how can we infer the return type from the function argument if it is a string array?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

how can we infer the return type from the function argument if it is a string array?

```
//   function subset(source: any, keys: string[], filter?: (key: string, value: any) => boolean): any

function subset<T extends { [key: string]: any }, U extends string[]>
(source: T, keys: U, filter?: (key: string, value: any) => boolean): Extract<T, keyof U> | T {
        if (!keys?.length || !source) { return source; }
        return keys.reduce((o, k) => {
            const value = source[k];
            if (!filter || filter(k, value)) {
                o[k] = value;
            }
            return o;
        }, {} as any);
    }
```

the commented signature is working but returns any, my goal is to infer the return type. and the second one always returns T (source type).

```
const obj = {name:'John',age:40, address:'xxxx'};
const sub1 = subset(obj,['name','age']); 
    // {name:'John',age:40}   //^? const sub1:any;
const sub2 = subset(obj,['age','address']) 
   // {age:40,address:'xxxx'}  //^? const sub2:any;
const sub3 = subset(obj) 
  // {name:'John',age:40, address:'xxxx'} //^? const sub3:any;
```

can you help me to infer the type for each case? Thank you

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/w29o8W) works for you

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a variant of `Pick`, which is implemented as

```
// https://github.com/Maggi64/moderndash/blob/main/package/src/object/pick.ts
export function pick<TObj extends PlainObject, Key extends keyof TObj>(object: TObj, keysToPick: Key[]): Pick<TObj, Key> {
    const result = {} as Pick<TObj, Key>;
    for (const key of keysToPick) {
        result[key] = object[key];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your `keys?: []` overloads seem weird, so it's removed

```
function pickBy<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(o: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K>;
function pickBy<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(o: T, keys: K[], filter: (k: K, v: T[K]) => boolean): Partial<Pick<T, K>>; // unknown subset of keys is removed
function pickBy<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(o: T, keys: K[], filter: (k: K, v: T[K]) => boolean): Partial<Pick<T, K>>; {
   if (o === null) return o;
   const result = {} as Pick<T, K>;
   for (const key of keys) {
      if (!filter || filter(k, object[key]))
         result[key] = object[key];
   }   
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but in the filter case, Partial did not help because the return type contains non-filtered keys. I was seeking something like Omit based on the filter callback result. but it did not work as I expected. please give it a look here https://tsplay.dev/wg834N, if it is always false or true works as expected but with the condition did not work, I think because the boolean always extends false. check the const sub2.

Comment: Filters MUST have `filter: (data) => data is Filtered` type so you can `Extract<data, Filtered>`. A good example is builtin `intreface Array<T>{  filter<S extends T>(predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S[];  }`

Comment: I think it's better to split the Pick? PickByFunction and Omit definitions for simplicity, and make their combination after they work well themselves